# Erratic behaviour of Python CGI-script on IIS7

Tags: python, iis-7, cgi

I am debugging a CGI script written in Python which executes on IIS. The script fails to generate a response 3 out of 4 times. Along with some standard modules I also import [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) and a custom module `<my_module>`.

For debugging purposes I commented out all the code except for module imports and the [mandatory](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) header response:

```
print('Status: 200 OK')
print('Content-type: text/html')
print('')

import <standard modules>
import boto
import <my_module>

# Commented out code below
# <code>
```

This way I found out that merely importing `<my_module>` drops the success rate from 100% to the aforementioned ~25%. Why could that be? What can I test to improve the situation?

The script works flawlessly on a local Apache. `<my_module>` is by far smaller than boto.

Thank you,

/David

Edit:
Ok, so I don't want to rush to conclusions here, but it looks like the 3rd party module [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=171) which is used within `<my_module>` has something to do with the issue. If I place said 3rd party module at the top of my import list in the main script things seem to work better.

Comment: You can use [cgitb](http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html) for debugging.

Comment: ... I do, but this is not a Python error.